# Editing Devexpress CodeRush SmartConstructor code template

Tags: templates, devexpress, coderush

How can I edit the behavior of the SmartConstructor TextCommand?

For class variables:

```
public string MyVar1;
public string MyVar2;
```

SmartConstructor generates

```
public Class1(string myVar1, string myVar2)
{
    MyVar1 = myVar1;
    MyVar2 = myVar2;
}
```

Is there any way to modify the code template so that it follows this coding standard instead?

```
public Class1(string pMyVar1, string pMyVar2)
{
    MyVar1 = pMyVar1;
    MyVar2 = pMyVar2;
}
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the DevExpress -> Options... menu.

Navigate to the Editor | Code Style | Identifiers option page.

Modify the Parameters naming style per your requirements.

Comment: Didn't know that menu existed! Thanks!